# Can you tell me about the Saint George day in Time of the Gypsies?

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, time-of-the-gypsies

In Time of the Gypsies, Perhan and his Girlfriend make love at the Saint George's day feast which takes place on a river:

[image]

Could you tell me more about this feast, from the Gypsies' point of view?

Is the Saint George Day from Time of the Gypsies according to some a real practice? Does the film portray this feast in a realistic manner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about real-world activities, as opposed to a question about the movie.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. *Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.*

Comment: Hi, no problem. I understand, but choosing the good stack was a huge hesitation for me between movies and christianity... I chose to post here because the question went to me by seeing the movie.

According to me, it is both a question about the gypsies' (what is the Saint George day for Gypsies'?) and the film (does the movie is realistic about this feast? Regarding the fireworks or the place, for example).

By the way, thanks for editing my question. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Serbia Saint George's day or [Đurđevdan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90ur%C4%91evdan) is a very important day for Serbian Romani. It is an Orthodox religious holiday.

This holiday celebrates the return of springtime and is considered the most important. The Romani will decorate their homes with flowers and wash their hands with water from a church well.
Lamb is traditionally cooked on this day and there is lots of music, singing, dancing and brass bands.